# Working with htaccess to display directories and files

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, xampp

I couldnt find a problem similar to mine, so here goes:
I have a web application where i display local directories and pdf files. Currently i am using htaccess to display these files in the browser, and ive written quite a lot in the .htaccess file, in order to style it (referencing header and footer.html to style, but in these .html files, the actual pdfs files arent displayed, there are only inline styled tags etc).

However, i now want the directories and files to be actual html code, so i can place on-clicks onto them, since my ultimate goal is to create a pop-up screen which then displays the clicked pdf file. This can only be done if i have the actual html code i believe. Any help would be appreciated, and just ask if you dont understand, but my problem is quite hard to describe.

[Current in-browser look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXfH5.png)

So my question, is there any way i can have my directories and files in html code, so i can work with it?

***My .htaccess file***

```
Options +Indexes

<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>

IndexOptions IgnoreCase FancyIndexing FoldersFirst NameWidth=* DescriptionWidth=* SuppressHTMLPreamble

IndexOrderDefault Descending Name

HeaderName /partials/header.html

ReadmeName /partials/footer.html

IndexIgnore ..
IndexIgnore header.html footer.html icons
IndexIgnore header.html footer.html favicon.ico .htaccess .ftpquota .DS_Store icons *.log *,v *,t .??* *~ *#

DefaultIcon /icons/generic.gif

AddIcon /icons/dir.gif ^^DIRECTORY^^

AddIcon /icons/pdf.gif .txt .pdf

AddIcon /icons/back.png ..

</IfModule>

Options -Indexes
```

Comment: I think you might need something like php to print your directory listing for you. [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dir.php)